# How do I get the Frame to collapse and expand when PaneDisplayMode is LeftCompact?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-navigation

When I set the PaneDisplayMode to LeftCompact, the NavigationPane overlaps on the frame. I'd like it to behave the same as when PaneDisplayMode is Left. Setting it to LeftCompact or LeftMinimal causes the Navigation flyout to overlap with the Frame. But Left causes the Frame to expand when the Navigation menu collapses, like it's supposed to. I'd like to get LeftCompact to do the same thing.

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.NavShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:wctoolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    KeyDown="NavShell_KeyDown"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background= "#FF474747">

    <!--"{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}     -->
    <Page.Resources>
        
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->

        <winui:MenuBar x:Name="MainMenu" Grid.Row="0">
            <winui:MenuBarItem Title="File">
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ImportMI" Text="Import Things" >
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="I"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ExportMI" Text="Export Things">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="E"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ExitMI" Text="Exit">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Windows" Key="X"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
            </winui:MenuBarItem>

            <winui:MenuBarItem Title="Edit">
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="CutMI" Text="Cut" >
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="X"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="CopyMI" Text="Copy" >
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="C"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="PasteMI" Text="Paste" >
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="V"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
            </winui:MenuBarItem>

            <winui:MenuBarItem Title="Help">
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="HelpAboutMI" Text="About">
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
            </winui:MenuBarItem>
        </winui:MenuBar>

 
        <winui:NavigationView x:Name="navMenu" IsBackEnabled="True" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                              IsSettingsVisible="True" SelectionChanged="navMenu_SelectionChanged" Header="My Test App"
                              AlwaysShowHeader="True" PaneTitle="Test App" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="100"
                              SelectionFollowsFocus="Enabled" IsTabStop="False" Grid.Row="1">
            <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <winui:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Things">
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        <winui:NavigationViewItem Icon="Document" Content="More Things">
                            <winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                                <winui:NavigationViewItem>
                                    <winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
                                        <winui:BitmapIconSource UriSource="NewFolder\Images\Things.png" />
                                    </winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
                                </winui:NavigationViewItem>
                            </winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
                    </winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                </winui:NavigationViewItem>
                <winui:NavigationViewItem Icon="Document" Content="Other Things">
                            
                </winui:NavigationViewItem>
            </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <winui:NavigationView.PaneCustomContent>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="PaneHyperlink" Content="More info" Margin="12,0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </winui:NavigationView.PaneCustomContent>


            <winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <StackPanel x:Name="SettingsFooter" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Icon="Setting" AutomationProperties.Name="settings" />
                </StackPanel>
            </winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>

            <Frame x:Name="NavContent" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">

            </Frame>
        </winui:NavigationView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like it to behave the same as when PaneDisplayMode is Left.

In a style of `NavigationView`, you could set the  `DisplayMode` property of `RootSplitView` which is the name of a `SplitView` in `NavigationView` to `CompactInline` to implement the operation.

Please check the following code:

1. Open the **Document Outline** panel, find and right-click your NavigationView `navMenu` **> Edit Template > Edit a Copy**. Then a default style of `NavigationView` will be copied to your `Page.Resource` tag and applied to your `NavigationView` control.
2. In the style, find a `VisualState` whose name is `Compact` and add the following code:

   ```
   <VisualState.Setters>
       <Setter Target="RootSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
   </VisualState.Setters>
   ```
3. Build your project.